# Botão para actualizar o texto em um campo de pesquisa mas introduzindo vários valores em sequência?

Tags: javascript, html

Com este código podemos enviar um só valor para o campo de pesquisa. Ora, tendo em conta este exemplo, como é que inserimos mais valores em sequência com o mesmo botão, por exemplo: valor 1, saude, divertir, ontem 5, etc.

Atenção que os valores não podem ser iguais e também é preciso que o valor anterior se apague e apareça o novo; ou seja, ao clicar o Valor 1 deve dar lugar a saude, saude deve dar lugar a divertir e assim sucessivamente.

http://jsfiddle.net/g506bxL4/1/

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
    <p>
        <input type="button" name="set_Value" id="set_Value" value="submit" onclick="setValue()" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            <input type="text" name="bbb" id="bbb" />
        </label>
    </p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    function setValue() {
    
        document.getElementById('bbb').value = "valor 1";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode manter o estado em uma lista de valores já adicionados. Daí a cada clique você adiciona um elemento a essa lista e atualiza a informação do campo.

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
    <p>
        <input type="button" name="set_Value" id="set_Value" value="submit" onclick="setValue()" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            <input type="text" name="bbb" id="bbb" />
        </label>
    </p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

    let values = [];


    function setValue() {
        let newValue = values.length + 1;
        values.push(`valor ${newValue}`);
        document.getElementById('bbb').value = values.join(', ');
    }
</script>
```

Veja que na função `setValue()`pegamos `values.length + 1`. Isso é para calcularmos o próximo número.

Depois disso adicionamos ao array `values` e depois atualizamos o valor do campo.

Comment: Não estou a conseguir resultados, talvez alguém possa alterar o código em http://jsfiddle.net/g506bxL4/1/, basta alterar e salvar para obter uma nova página e endereço.

Comment: Atenção, é preciso que o valor anterior se apague e apareça o novo; ou seja, ao clicar o valor1 deve dar lugar ao valor2 e assim sucessivamente. Talvez alguém possa alterar o código em http://jsfiddle.net/g506bxL4/1/, basta alterar e salvar para obter uma nova página e endereço.

Comment: E os valores não podem ser iguais, por exemplo Valor 1, saúde, divertir, ontem 5... e também é preciso que o valor anterior se apague e apareça o novo; ou seja, ao clicar o Valor 1 deve dar lugar a saude 2, saude deve dar lugar a divertir,  e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: Você pode pegar esse exemplo e aplicar a sua necessidade.